# Cannot login to win10 on Esxi using console: "The number of connections to this computer is limited and all connections are in use right now"

Tags: windows-10, login

Suddenly I cannot login to a win10 vm on esxi any more using Vmware remote console or remote desktop.
The message I get is: **The number of connections to this computer is limited and all connections are in use right now**. I have already tried all the suggestions found in internet such as restart, unplug lan cable and add registry keys to increment the number of connections.

The problem I'm experiencing is almost the same described [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29127501/Error-logging-in-The-number-of-connections-to-this-computer-is-limited-and-all-connections-are-in-use-right-now.html) where I cannot read the accepted answer.

Can this weird behavior be related to a windows activation problem ?

Comment: Does the problem go away if you reboot the Windows VM? Are there other connections to the VM beside the console login?

Comment: @harrymc
I wrote: 

    "I have already tried all the suggestions found in internet such as restart, unplug lan cable and add registry keys to increment the number of connections."


So I rooted the vm several times and there a re no rdp connections, besides I think a console connection has precedence on rdp connections, anyway I don't know how **Vmware remote console** works.

Comment: In previous comment I did a typo. **rooted --> rebooted**